# How can I compare object with another object

Tags: java

I run the following

```
Choice choice1 = new Choice(0);
       Choice choice2 = new Choice(1);
       int result = choice1.compareWith(choice2);

       IO.outputln("Actual: " + result);
```

the compareWith method

```
public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice)
    {

        int result=0;           
        if (anotherChoice==0||type==0)
            result=1;
        if (anotherChoice==1&&type==1)
        result=-11;
    }
```

The program said that i can not compare anotherchoice (choice class) with a integer. How can I do it.

Comment: as the error says, anotherchoice is of type `Choice`. I assume you want to compare instance variable `type`. So it should be `anotherChoice.type == this.type`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (anotherChoice==0||type==0)
```

Since `anotherChoice` is an object you cannot directly compare with `0`. You should actually check a field of that object. So your code should be

```
if (anotherChoice.type==0|| this.type==0)
```

Same for the other condition.

And another error is that you are not returning anything from your method. You should.

```
public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice)
    {

        int result=0;           
        if (anotherChoice==0||type==0)
            result=1;
        if (anotherChoice==1&&type==1)
        result=-11;

       return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be implementing `Comparable` for this. You should also need to get the `type` value out of the Choice when you are comparing the values:

```
public class Choice implements Comparable<Choice>
{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Choice that)
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (anotherChoice.type == 0 || type == 0)
            result = 1;
        if (anotherChoice.type == 1 && type == 1)
            result = -11; // should probably be -1

        return result;
    }
}
```